# Ktor: testing REST endpoints using Spek/KotlinTest instad of JUnit Test Class

Tags: ktor, spek, kotlintest

I have a simple hello world Ktor app:

```
fun Application.testMe() {
  intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
    if (call.request.uri == "/")
      call.respondText("Hello")
    }
}
```

With JUnit test class I can write the test for it, as given in its documentation; as following:

```
class ApplicationTest {
    @Test fun testRequest() = withTestApplication(Application::testMe) {
        with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/")) {
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            assertEquals("Hello", response.content)
        }
        with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/index.html")) {
            assertFalse(requestHandled)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to do a unit test in Spek or KotlinTest, without the help of JUnit, similar to the way I do it in ScalaTest/Play; in a more declarative way:

1. Send a FakeRequest to the route (i.e., `/`) during a test.
2. Get the content of the page, and check for the string "hello".

The question is can I write the above test in a more declarative way in KotlinTest or Spek?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, follow [spek setup guide with JUnit 5](http://spekframework.org/docs/latest/)

Then you can simply declare you specifications like the following

```
object HelloApplicationSpec: Spek({
    given("an application") {
        val engine = TestApplicationEngine(createTestEnvironment())
        engine.start(wait = false) // for now we can't eliminate it
        engine.application.main() // our main module function

        with(engine) {
            on("index") {
                it("should return Hello World") {
                    handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/").let { call ->
                        assertEquals("Hello, World!", call.response.content)
                    }
                }
                it("should return 404 on POST") {
                    handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/", {
                        body = "HTTP post body"
                    }).let { call ->
                        assertFalse(call.requestHandled)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Here is my build.gradle (simplified)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek" }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

junitPlatform {
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'spek'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.5'
    testRuntime 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5'
    testCompile "io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:$ktor_version"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.